# ¿Como Conectar Múltiples bases de datos con Entity Framework dentro del mismo edmx en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, base-de-datos, entity-framework-6

Tengo mi proyecto de C# el cual se conecta por Entity Framework a una base de datos Mysql (modelada previamente en Mysql), el modelo .edmx lo cree con “Generate From Database”, mi intención es crear en base al .edmx una nueva base de datos en SqlServer y poder seleccionar una base de datos u otra, dependiendo lo que solicite el usuario.

Comment: has intentado algo?

Comment: @fredyfx Si, pero para tener dos bases de datos diferentes a la vez, pero necesito algo como poder seleccionar una base de datos u otra según la bd que posea el cliente (MySQL, oracle o sqlserver).

Comment: me llama la atención el escenario donde estás, podrías darnos mayores detalles por favor?

Comment: Tengo un proyecto funcional con MySQL, pero mi idea es tener en alguna parte de la aplicación un configurador donde yo pueda elegir que bd usare, osea intercambiarla por sqlserver o MySQL sin tener que recompilar el codigo cambiando la configuración del EF. Se que hay maneras ya que lo he visto en otros proyectos, podría hacer intercambio de lib's al seleccionar la bd pero pienso que si existe alguna forma de crearlo automáticamente  con VS sería lo mejor, me ha pasado que pierdo una semana o más creando una solución  y luego descubro que me demoro sólo horas con automátizacion de VS.

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a usar una o la otra, solo tendrías que modificar la conexión para que se conecte a *MySQL*, algo como esto:

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********"/>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

... y para que se conecte  a *SQL*:

```
 <add name="MyContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Integration.Models.MyContext.csdl|res://*/Integration.Models.MyContext.ssdl|res://*/Integration.Models.MyContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=db_SQL;user id=sa;password=********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

El `name` tendría que ser el mismo y modificar tu archivo **.config** según la base de datos a la que te vayas a conectar.

Toma en cuenta que necesitarás agregar las referencias necesarias para cada caso.

Si quieres usar ambas bases de datos a las vez, tendrías que crear dos conexiones y de alguna manera cambiarlas en *runtime*, cambiarle la conexión al *context*.

Answer (score 0):

No basta con cambiar el string de conexion. Tambien tienes que cambiar las clases. Cada motor de base de datos , tiene sus propias clases.  SqlConnection es  sql server, AseConnexion de sybase,
MySqlConnexion de mysql, etc.